# Tring to display a checkmark("✓") in a html report from a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, checkmark

I am trying to display checkmark in a html page from jsp file. But it is displaying as '?'

I added '<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>' to jsp page, but no luck,

Action class:

```
char checkMark = '\u2713';
b.setString8(String.valueOf(checkMark));
```

JSP page:

```
<td align="center"> <bean:write name="status" property="string8" /> </td>
```

And it is displayed as

[image]

Can you please help me?

Comment: Adding `charset=UTF-8` is not sufficient. If the corresponding font is not installed in the system where the page is being viewed, `✓` will be displayed as a `?`. You should add an image instead.

Comment: Just a guess, but try to find encoding settings for your *whole project* and see if it is set to UTF-8.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash: can you elaborate what do you mean by image?

Comment: Like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=tickmark+image)